# Collapsed flags not helpful on Stack Overflow Documentation edit suggestions

Tags: feature-request, documentation, user-experience

> Was deleted and the code is fine, I don't understand why ~ Lito ~ https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31846184#31846184

Please, search on this page what's wrong with it. The information is all there:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/21608

[image: screeeeeen]

But… it's actually hidden. The improvement request *message* is **collapsed**.

You first have to click on the orange "Handles improvement requests submitted" box to find out about the real reason.

**Suggested solution**: Have improvement request info **expanded** by default on the improvement request page:

[image: better]